# Padding around elements in a matrix

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to adjust the padding around elements in a matrix, as indicated in the figure below.

[image: Example of cramped matrix]

The code is shown below

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

... in general we have

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots &
        \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots &
        \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

and for the particular case of $m=n=2$ 

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\
        \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}


Is it possible to insert some space around the elements in (2)? The matrix looks a bit cramped.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cellspace` package wiith option `[math]` does that.

Comment: The package `nicematrix` provides tools to control that and also many other points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code with `cellspace`. Unrelated: I suggest using the `diffcoeff`  package to simplify typing of partial derivatives, and the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` to have medium-sized fractions in matrices (the default is `\tfrac`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\[ J = \begin{pmatrix}
        \medmath{\diffp{f_1}{x_1}} & \medmath{\diffp{f_1}{x_2}} \\
         \medmath{\diffp{f_2}{x_1}} & \medmath{\diffp{f_2}{x_2}}
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

 \end{document}
```

[image]